# How to prepare JSON object for d3 graph building?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am writing a small application that would parse xml file and then create a graph out of it using [d3.js](http://d3js.org/).

So far I have build the following script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  var mydata = new Array(1);
  $.get("testcase.xml", function(xml) {
      $(xml).find('measurement').each(function(){
        var meas = $(this); 
        var type = meas.find('type').text();
        var interval = meas.find('interval').text();

        mydata.push({'type': type, 'interval': interval});

      });

      var ch = d3.select("body")
          .append("ul")
          .selectAll("li")
          .data(mydata)
          .enter()
          .append("li")
          .text(function(d){
              return d.type + ": " + d.interval;
              });
    });

});
</script>
```

I am pretty sure I am building the `mydata` array in a wrong way but I am getting 5 bullet points (that many `measurement` tags I have in my `testcase.xml` but **they do not contain the data that I have build up in mydata variable**).

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I am not getting `d.type + ":" + d.interval` in the list. Only the empty `<li>` elements.

Comment: Can you post the HTML output that you're getting?

Comment: Ok (omg) I have solved it. The problem for this was that I have been creating `new Array(1)` and then after appending data, I was trying to read `.type` property of `undefined`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved it ( as posted in the comment ) :

The problem for this was that I have been creating `new Array(1)` and then after appending data, I was trying to read `.type property` of `undefined` (which was the first element in the array.